# How to let `concurrent.futures` handle streaming tasks?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

`concurrent.futures` is a python package designed for asynchronously executing tasks.
A typical usage of it is as follows (copied from [link](https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-wait-vs-as-completed/)):

```py
# SuperFastPython.com
# example of waiting for all tasks in a collection of tasks to be done
from time import sleep
from random import random
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import wait
 
# custom task that will sleep for a variable amount of time
def task(name):
    # sleep for less than a second
    sleep(random())
    # display the result
    print(name)
 
# start the thread pool
with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as executor:
    # submit tasks and collect futures
    futures = [executor.submit(task, i) for i in range(10)]
    # wait for all tasks to complete
    wait(futures)
    print('All tasks are done!')
```

The work mode of `concurrent.futures` is

1. submit to-do tasks to the `ThreadPoolExecutor`
2. The package automatically executes all to-do tasks, and

- *wait* (achieved by `wait()`) for tasks to finish/except or
- return a sequence of tasks (achieved by `as_completed()`) that are ordered in their finishing time.

Such work mode is like, you submit some tasks to the thread pool, then wait for all to finish / iterate through all tasks. The next time we submit to the thread pool, it is exhausted (no task in it).

**But** now I am working on a new problem, where I have streaming tasks (task may come one by one or batch by batch, but not all of them come together), and I want to submit them into the thread pool continuously (submit batch by batch, instead of submit all of them at once), then have an Iterable (possibly like what `as_completed()` do) to receive any task that finishes (in finishing time order).

How can this be achieved by `concurrent.futures`? If this package does not support the feature, is there any other solution?

Comment: You can solve this by adding a done callback function to the Furure for each task and having the function report the first result seen. See an example here: https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-first-result-from-stream/